# I am getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when trying to call an API

Tags: angularjs, api, cors, jsonp, mean-stack

*Edit: It may be worth noting that I am domain registered at GoDaddy which forwards with masking to my Bitnami IP.  My stack is all on the same server, that's why I do not understand the cross site nature of this issue.  Or maybe I am understanding it wrong.  Please help me understand this error.*

I know there are other threads similar to this, but I didn't see any matching my exact setup.

I have an Amazon AWS EC2 Bitnami MEAN stack running an AngularJS site.  I am posting some info I gathered externally with some Python scripts into a mongodb and then I have a JS API that successfully posts the collection via port 3000 ... all pretty standard from what I can tell.  I am just learning this technology and am pretty novice.

So When I go to the API **[URL]:3000/api** in Chrome I see the JSON results.  This has not been a problem.

When my Angular site's controller tries to do a $http GET on the API URL, Express logs and displays in my putty console to Bitnami that I am indeed hitting the API.

BUT.. Chrome is giving me this sweet error on the page when I F12 debug:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load **URL**. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin **URL**' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Sorry for all the fake URLs, I'm newer to stackoverflow and it flagged me as using "more than 2 URLs" because I don't have 10 points.

Thank you so much in advance for helping me understand this problem.

Comment: can't redirect ajax request cross domain like that...have your host server act as proxy and get the data. Also note that different port constitutes different origin with regard to CORS

Comment: @charlietfl I saw this solution somewhere else too.  Again forgive my noviceness.  Can you please link something ELI5-like as to how to accomplish that proxy or reverse proxy setup?  For now this IS working with the solution below, allowing all CORS.  I have GETs only and it is a public free website so no security issues there really, but I would like to do it RIGHT. =o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is simple, you are making an API call to as separate domain from the one your angular app is being served from. Chrome or any other browser will normally throw a CORS error.

What you will have to do is to go to your API and whitelist the domain from which your angular app is running. I am not sure how it is done in python, but in NodeJS below is what I will do.

```
var cors = require('cors');
corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    'http://www.127.0.0.1:5555',
    'http://www.any-other-site-to-access.com'
  ],
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

For python this might help, not sure
http://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html

From the documentation of CORS, to enable all CORS

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/products/:id', function(req, res, next){
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'});
});

app.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
});
```

Comment: don't think it will work that way if it is a redirect....might be wrong but it would take the normal preflight process out of the loop

Comment: @charlietfl I am not sure I understand what you mean, if he sets `self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` I think it should handle all incoming request, even if it is a redirect

Comment: So I tried to sudo npm install cors on the EC2 Bitnami and it will not let me.  The error I get is this:  └── cors@2.8.1  extraneous
Also, I edited my httpd.conf as per this page and still no love:  http://awesometoast.com/cors/

Comment: @TomV I think that is a separate problem, and I am not sure I have enough inforamtion to know why you are having the error

Comment: I'm on the EC2 AWS stack running Bitnami MEAN virtually.  Won't let me install the cors package =o(  ... I've read that this is a server side problem and that editing your Apache2 config will fix it.  So far no luck.

Comment: Okay I am using the use cors and it runs when i do a ../bin/www but still getting the same error on F12 debug.  Sigh

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Hey in your above example of Cors Options how would I allow all?  Sorry please forgive my newbieness/ignorance.

Comment: To anyone reading this, if I added the recommended configs from https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/ -- where in my httpd.conf would I add these, under what section?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @TomV Sorry I have been away

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge No worries.  So I don't have "the reputation" to chat (despite being on here 2 years just not very active participation wise)... do you know where to add those entries to httpd.conf?  I tried Directory and no go.

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Thank you, you beautiful son-of-a-bitch.  It worked.  The CORS open all.  Not sure if it was a combo of that AND my Apache2 httpd.conf changes or what but thank you good sir.